# CoreDataで並び順を保存したい

Tags: swift, ios

Swif t3でのCoreDataに保存したデータの並び順を保存する方法について教えてください。
要素にtitleとurl(どちらもString型)を持つbookmarkエンティティがあります。
これらの各要素をtableviewに表示しています。編集ボタンを押してtableviewを編集したあと、
その並びをCoreDataに反映させたいのですが、良い方法が浮かびません。現在、下記のコードのように擬似的に並び替えを行なっています。

```
// 並び替え後の処理
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    // bookmarkListにはCoreDataから読み込んだデータが格納されている
    let moveData = bookmarkList[sourceIndexPath.row] // 移動先のデータを格納
    bookmarkList.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row) //元の位置のデータを配列から削除する。
    bookmarkList.insert(moveData, at:destinationIndexPath.row) //移動先の位置にデータを配列に挿入する。
    deleteBookmark() // 一旦CoreDataの中身を全て削除
    for bookmark in bookmarkList { // 再度並び替え後のデータを保存
       addBookmark(aTitle: bookmark.Title!, aUrl: bookmark.Url!)
    }
}
// CoreDataからの削除関数
func deleteBookmark() {
    let query: NSFetchRequest<MyBookmark> = MyBookmark.fetchRequest()

    do {
        let fetchResults = try context.fetch(query)
        for result: AnyObject in fetchResults {
            let record = result as! NSManagedObject
            context.delete(record)
        }
        try context.save()
    } catch {
    }
}
// CoreData新規登録関数
func addBookmark(aTitle: String, aUrl: String) {
    let mybookmark = MyBookmark(context: context)

    // 既に登録されているものは登録されないようにURLで検索する。
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<MyBookmark> = MyBookmark.fetchRequest()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"%K = %@","Url","\(aUrl)")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    let fetchData = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)

    if fetchData.isEmpty {
        // 新しく登録する
        if aTitle != "" && aUrl != ""  {
            mybookmark.Title = aTitle
            mybookmark.Url = aUrl
        }
        do{
            try context.save()
        }catch{
        }
    }else{
        context.reset()
    }
}
```

上のコードのように、一旦CoreDataの中身をからにして、並び替えたデータを再度保存しています。一応これでも動くのですがスマートではありません。データベースのように好きなところにデータをインサートする方法を教えて欲しいです。(CoreDataの中身を見るとz_pkという主キーのようなものがあるのを見つけました。これを上手く使えばできるのでしょうか？)

Comment: 表示上の並び順を表すカラムを追加するのではだめでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一般的なデータベースではオブジェクトの並び順は保存されません。ですので、並び順を示すカラムを追加して、それを用いて並べ替えを行う必要があります。
CoreDataの場合、結果の並べ替えには`NSSortDiscriptor`を使います。

汎用的な方法としては並び順を示すカラムをモデルに追加し、のタイミング(`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)`)でそのカラムの値を更新します。

もしくは、例外的にCoreDataはOrderedSetという並び順を保持するデータ型がありますので、関連を作って一段階ラップして利用するのも有効です。そうすると、おそらくより直感的にやりたいことが実現できると思います。

Comment: ご解答ありがとうございます。並び順を示すカラムをIDカラムとして追加し、初めのデータに1を付与して、データが追加されるたびIDをインクリメントしてIDを付与し、そのIDカラムを元にデータを降順or昇順等に並び替えると思うのですが、例えば、データが6つあった時、IDカラムが5のデータをID3のデータのところに移動する場合、IDカラム5のデータのIDを3に書き換えて、旧ID3のデータをID4に、旧ID4のデータを5に書き換えることで、並び順を変更することができると考えました。この認識であっていますでしょうか。また、一意のIDを書き換える際に使用するメソッド等ご存知でしたら教えて頂けると助かります。

Comment: 普通はIDを並び替えのために更新することはしません。IDを変更してしまうと外部からは並べ替えではなくレコードそのものが変わってしまったように見えます。普通に並び順のカラムを追加することをお勧めします。